# Reverse proxy fail request after failure in jwt parsing

Tags: http, go, proxy, jwt, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy, it validates *jwt* from headers and enriches data,
when an expired *jwt* arrives the proxy returns an error to the user and *status code 502* (with the correct error) - which is good!

After that, every request that arrives with valid *jwt* is returning an error with message: `crypto/rsa: verification error`

However, when extracting the *jwt* from the request and checking it locally I found that everything works perfectly.

The proxy code:

```golang
parsedUrl, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:" + environment.ProxyPort)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(parsedUrl)
proxy.FlushInterval = 200 * time.Millisecond
proxy.Transport = &myTransport{}
proxy.ModifyResponse = func(r *http.Response) error {
    return nil
}

proxy.ErrorHandler = func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
    logs.Log(err.Error(), logs.Error)
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadGateway)
    if _, err := rw.Write([]byte(`{"source": "enrich-sidecar", error": "` + err.Error() + `"}`)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

req.URL.Host = parsedUrl.Host
req.URL.Scheme = parsedUrl.Scheme
req.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Header.Get("Host"))
req.Host = parsedUrl.Host

proxy.ServeHTTP(res, req)
```

The validation:

```golang
if err := validateAlg(jwtToken); err != nil {
    return false, nil, err
}

token, err := jwt.Parse(jwtToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return key, nil
})

if err != nil {
    return false, nil, err
} else if !token.Valid {
    return false, nil, token.Claims.Valid()
}
```

Comment: What `validateAlg` function is doing?

Comment: this function validate the algorithem in header section of the jwt

Comment: Could you please post somewhere (may be a private github repo) the whole code? Possibly there's no available secret key or some headers to check correctness.